# How to remove all of the typed commands from the command window?

Tags: r

In R, how to remove all of the typed commands from the command window, so that I can have a clearer working environment.

Comment: Multi-platform solution: hold the <Enter> key for awhile...

Comment: another multi-platform solution. quit R using `q()` and restart :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**On windows using RGui, a mac inside the terminal, or on Linux:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will clear the screen for you.  You won't be able to scroll up to view what you've done in the session previously though.  You can still use the up arrow to scroll through your history though.

**On a mac using the gui:** <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will do the same thing as clearing in the windows gui.

**On any system:** You could create a function to do something similar to clearing the screen for you:

`clr <- function(){cat(rep("\n", 50))}`

All this does is prints enough linebreaks to essentially push everything above what is viewable on the console.  You can still scroll up to view the previous output but you'll have 50 lines of whitespace.  Depending on your monitor size you might need to increase the number of line breaks to clear everything.

Answer (score 3):

As others pointed out its <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> otherwise you may find this helpful *if you are using Windows*: [function to clear screen](http://onertipaday.blogspot.com/2007/05/how-to-clear-screen-in-r.html)

The functions that appear in that blog post seem to be copied (without giving attribution) from [this r-help post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-February/088507.html) and [this r-help post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-February/088585.html).

EDIT:

Added caveat about Windows and also link to original original source.

Answer (score 1):

In RGui, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and you should have a clean command line window.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
cls <- function(){
  if (getIdentification() == 'R Console')
    cat('\f')                         # R Console
  else{
    if (Sys.info()[['sysname']] == 'windows')
      system('powershell clear-host') # Windows
    else
      system('clear')                 # *Unix
  }
}
```

this function may works both on windows, and *Unix.

i don't have a computer runs *Unix system, if this code works on Mac or Linux, let me know.